# PHP Readfile() number of bytes when user aborted

Tags: php

I'm using a PHP script to stream a live video (i.e. a file which never ends) from a remote source. The output is viewed in VLC, not a web browser. I need to keep a count of the number of bytes transferred. Here is my code:

```
<?php

ignore_user_abort(true);
$stream = $_GET['stream'];

if($stream == "vid1")
{
    $count = readfile('http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
    logThis($count);
}

function logThis($c)
{
    $myFile = "bytecount.txt";
    $handle = fopen($myFile,'a');
    fwrite($handle,"Count: " . $c . "\n");
    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

However it appears that when the user presses the stop button, logThis() is never called, even though I've put in ignore_user_abort(true);

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

**Update2**: I've changed my code as I shoudn't be using ignore_user_abort(true) as that would continue to download the file forever even after the client has gone. I've changed my code to this:

```
<?php

$count = 0;

function bye()
{
    //Create Dummy File with the filename of equal to count
}

register_shutdown_function('bye');
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(false);

$stream = $_GET['stream'];

if($stream == "vid1")
{
    $GLOBALS['count'] = readfile('http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
    exit();
}
```

?>

My problem now is that when the script is aborted (i.e. user presses stop), readfile won't return a value (i.e. count remains at 0). Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: try adding: `set_time_limit(0)`, also reading the following may help! http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

Comment: readfile isn't returning 0 when the use aborts - it's returning boolean false, since a user abort is an error condition. It'll only return the transferred-bytes count if the whole file was queued successfully. e.g. you can't use it at all to determine how much had been sent before the abort occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok folks I managed to fix this. The trick was to not use readfile() but read the video stream byte by byte. Ok it may not be 100% accurate, however a few bytes inaccuracy here or there is ok.

```
<?php

$count = 0;

function logCount()
{
    //Write out dummy file with a filename equal to count
}

register_shutdown_function('logCount');
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(false);

$stream = $_GET['stream'];

if($stream == "vid1")
{

    $filename = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/';
    $f = fopen($filename, "rb");

    while($chunk = fread($f, 1024)) {
        echo $chunk;
        flush();
        if(!connection_aborted()) {
            $GLOBALS['count'] += strlen($chunk);
        }
        else {
            exit();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> When a PHP script is running normally the NORMAL state, is active. If the remote client disconnects the ABORTED state flag is turned on. A remote client disconnect is usually caused by the user hitting his STOP button. If the PHP-imposed time limit (see set_time_limit()) is hit, the TIMEOUT state flag is turned on.

so setting the `set_time_limit` to 0 should help.

Comment: Nope sorry, adding set_time_limit to 0 didn't change anything I'm afraid. My text file still isn't being written to once the stop button is pressed.